# How to Change the Confirm box buttons and Display the error logo using asp.net 2.0?

Tags: asp.net

i am developing one asp.net application,i am using one gridview and bind the data and one delete button also displayed, so click the delete button first display the confirm message box.(Do u want Delete?) ,confirm box display the ok and cancel buttons but my problem is i want to display the Yes and No buttons and display the error image . How to write the code in RowDeleting Event or Any javaScript, pls tel me it is very urgent

Thank u
hemanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the Ajax Control Toolkit's confirm button extender have a look here [Confirm Button  Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx) also math berseths post also will you help you with the code. Look here [Including Yes/No in gridview](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/confirm_gridview_deletes_with.html)

Comment: but i doesnot use Ajax i am using 2.0 (VS2005) i is not supporting fully

Comment: lol who says asp.net ajax control toolkit isn't available for visual studio 2005 `http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/11121` get the version 1.0.X